# Slim no registra y no actualiza los datos en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, slim3

Estoy creando una API REST con slimframework y una librería llamada fluentPDO pero tengo problemas al momento de registrar y actulizar los datos.

Este es el fragmento de código de empleado_model.php

```
public function registrar($data) {
    $data['Password'] = md5($data['Password']);
    $this->db->insertInto($this->table, $data)->execute();
    return $this->response->SetResponse(true);
}
```

y este es el de rutas:

```
$this->post('registrar', function ($req, $res, $args) {
    return $res->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
        ->write(json_encode($this->model->empleado->registrar($req->getParsedBody())));
    });
```

Al momento de realizar la petición por POST no registra los datos en la BD pero me devuelve el código 200 OK con el siguiente error (lo mismo pasa para el método PUT):

```
{"result":null,"response":true,"message":"","errors":[]}
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\Tests\Toby\vendor\lichtner\fluentpdo\FluentPDO\BaseQuery.php on line 293
```

Comment: Hola Antony hoy te daré el mejor consejo que jamas podrán darte, NO uses **fluentPDO** el motivo es que nadie le esta dando seguimiento, las consultas como where or no existen y los joins funcionan mal, usa mejor pdo o implementa eloquent orm si te agrada mas, ya que hagas esos cambios intentan hacer las consultas nuevamente y veremos como ayudarte. PD: en caso de que quieras seguir con fluentpdo valida si la informacion que agregas a tu array de $datos tiene los mismos nombres que tu base de datos. Saludos.